# Getting a daily summary of figures from shop database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables, in a standard shop:

(`id` is always primary key, auto-increment, `ts` is always type `TIMESTAMP`, updated ON_UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

table `sales`:

```
id | total | tendered | flag | userID | ts
1     0.6      0.6       0       4      2013-11-21 08:12:23
```

`Sales` is the parent table, `userID` is related to the user that made the sale.  `total` and `tendered` are both of type FLOAT.  `flag` is of type VARCHAR and could be `Free Order`.

table `receipts`:

```
id | oID | pID | quantity | ts
1     1     26      1       2013-11-21 08:11:25
```

`Receipts` holds a line for each unique type of product sold.  `oID` is type INT and relates to the `id` of table `sales`.  `pID` is of type INT and relates to the `id` of table `products`.

table `products`:

```
id | name | price | cID | display | ts
1    Mars    0.6     3      1       2014-01-17 07:55:25
```

`Products` is the central data for each product in the database.  Here is a line for mars bars.  `cID` relates to the `id` in table `categories`.

table `categories`

```
id | name | display | ts
3   Snacks     1      2013-11-14 12:06:44
```

`Categories` is the table  holding all the data about each category, and can have multiple products relating to a single row.  `display` is of type INT and dictates when the category is enabled or disabled (1 = 'true')

My question is, I want to output information like this:

```
**Snacks**
(name)  (quantity) (price) (total)
Fruit      3         50p     £1.50
Twix       1         60p     60p
Boost      1         60      60p

**Hot Drinks**
(name)          (quantity) (price) (total)
English Tea 15      60p      £9.00
Speciality Teas 2       60p      £1.20
```

Which I have the following SQL for:

```
SELECT categories.name AS category, products.name, pID, 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM receipts WHERE pID=r.pID AND DATE(ts) = CURDATE()) AS quantity,
products.price,r.ts
FROM receipts r
LEFT JOIN products ON r.pID = products.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.cID = categories.id
WHERE DATE(r.ts) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY r.pID
ORDER BY categories.name;
```

Which seems to give me the correct information, but I am not 100% certain.  If anyone could verify that this works, I would be most grateful.  But when I want to see a particular day, I get unusual figures with the following SQL:

```
$postfrom = $_POST['from_mm']."/".$_POST['from_dd']."/20".$_POST['from_yy'];
$postto = $_POST['to_mm']."/".$_POST['to_dd']."/20".$_POST['to_yy'];

$from = strtotime($postfrom . " 6:00");
$to = strtotime($postto . " 23:59");
$itemised = select("SELECT categories.name AS category, products.name, pID, 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM receipts WHERE pID = r.pID AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.ts) > '{$from}' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.ts) < '{$to}') 
AS quantity, products.price
FROM receipts r
LEFT JOIN products ON r.pID = products.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.cID = categories.id
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.ts) > '{$from}'
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.ts) < '{$to}'
GROUP BY r.pID
ORDER BY categories.name;");
```

(*function 'select'* simply returns an array of the SQL table).  The thing is, I could find the results easily by looping through in PHP and adding it up that way.  But I know this is possible with SQL, I just don't know why It isnt working.  Can somebody please help?

**Edit** SQL sample fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23af4 although I couldn't do more than half a day of data due to 8000 character restrictions.

Comment: Rather than all this, just provide proper DDLs - TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT and your best effort to date. And usual caveats about (suspected) deprecated functions and un-escaped data

Comment: Maybe you could provide a SQLFiddle with some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't really know what your refering to by DDLs.  I thought providing as much information as possible would help solve the problem.

Comment: I will (and I am in process of) creating and SQL fiddle.

Comment: @Chud37 Oke, that would help a lot. Because now I know you have a problem, but I haven't got a clue what you want to achieve.

Comment: DDLs are the CREATE and INSERT statements used to (re)create your database.

Comment: It is jolly hard to get the `DDL` (whatever that means) down to 8000 characters.

Comment: Lets do it in steps. Start with SHOW CREATE TABLE nametable. Copy everthing in for example a notepad file and then copy to SQLFiddle. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: @chud37 have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT categories.name AS category, products.name AS name, 
receipts.quantity AS quantity, products.price AS price,
(receipts.quantity * products.price) AS total
FROM categories
JOIN products
ON categories.id = products.cID
JOIN receipts
ON receipts.pID = products.ID

WHERE DATE(receipts.ts) = CURDATE()
ORDER BY categories.name
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb716/28)

With regard to the date restriction, you could use BETWEEN ... AND ...  to specify the date and time. Using an absolute date and time moment or relative to the current day and time, for example WHERE DATE(receipts.ts) BETWEEN concat(curdate() -5,' 6:00:00 AM') AND curdate() -4